# Definitive way to configure network devices in Centos 6.2

Tags: linux, networking, centos, networkmanager

What is the definitive way to configure network devices in Centos 6.2? Via network manager or editing `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`?

I have a notebook with 1 ethernet port and a usb ethernet adapter plugged in.

When I do `ip link show` I see `eth0` and `em1`. However when I go to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`, there is an `ifcfg-eth0` file and `ifcfg-usb0`, but no `ifcfg-em1`.

The network manager applet shows under Wired connections System eth0 and System usb0. I have set eth0 to 10.0.4.24 and usb0 to use dhcp under the network manager applet.

When I remove usb ethernet device, `ip link show` only shows `em1`. Does this mean `em1` maps to `eth0`? However as `eth0` is no longer there (because the usb adapter has been removed), does that mean `usb0` also maps to `eth0`?

My problem is that when I do an `ifconfig`, BOTH `em1` and `eth0` show an ip address of `10.0.4.24`.

PS should this belong here or at serverfault?

edit: added requested output:

```
# more 70-persistent-net.rules 
# This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules
# program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.
#
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single
# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key.

# PCI device 0x8086:0x422b (iwlagn)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="24:77:03:74:85:98", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

# USB device 0x0b95:0x7720 (usb)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:50:b6:50:b5:fc", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

---------------------

# more ifcfg-eth0 
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO=none
#HWADDR="00:21:70:B9:4C:9F" # Commented by Clonezilla
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth0"
UUID=5fb06bd0-0bb0-7ffb-45f1-d6edd65f3e03
IPADDR=10.0.4.24
PREFIX=24

-----------------------

# more ifcfg-usb0 
DEVICE="usb0"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="no"
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System usb0"
UUID=689ce77b-bfa1-c10b-19a2-eb3a89251128
HWADDR=02:80:37:EC:02:00
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes

-------------------------

# ifconfig
em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D4:BE:D9:2B:D3:72  
          inet addr:10.0.4.24  Bcast:10.0.4.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d6be:d9ff:fe2b:d372/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:120 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:57 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:11475 (11.2 KiB)  TX bytes:10552 (10.3 KiB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:e6e00000-e6e20000 

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:B6:50:B5:FC  
          inet addr:10.0.4.24  Bcast:10.0.4.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:b6ff:fe50:b5fc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1000 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:473 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:87868 (85.8 KiB)  TX bytes:56643 (55.3 KiB)
```

Note there is no entry in ifconfig or ip link for usb0

Comment: Please paste here output of following files:
`/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`
`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`
`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-usb0`

Comment: hi, added the output to the bottom of the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NetworkManager, that is the way forward. It used to do weird things a while back, but that has been ironed out now. If you have some exotic setup, try to integrate it there. Only edit the files under `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` by hand as last resort.